Blowup of diagonal in $\mathbb{P}^r \times \mathbb{P}^r$
Let $X= \mathbb{P}^r \times \mathbb{P}^r$. Suppose we blowup $X$ along $\Delta$ the diagonal to get $\tilde X$. I want to show that this is isomorphic to the fibre product which I describe below -
Let $\mathbb Gr(1 , \mathbb P^r)$ be the Grasmannian variety parameterising lines in $\mathbb P^r$. Let $U \to \mathbb Gr( 1 ,\mathbb P^r)$ be the universal bundle over it. Consider the fibre product $U \times_{\mathbb Gr(1 \times \mathbb P^r)} U$.

Why is $\tilde X \cong U \times_{\mathbb Gr(1 , \mathbb P^r)} U $?


There is a natural morphism
$$
f \colon X := U \times_{\mathrm{Gr}(1,r)} U \to \mathbb{P}^r \times \mathbb{P}^r =: Y,
$$
so it is enough to check that $f$ is the blowup of the diagonal. One way to do this is by using Lemma 2.5 from [Kuznetsov, A. G. On linear sections of the spinor tenfold. I. Izv. Math. 82 (2018), no. 4, 694--751], where $E$ is the diagonal in $X$ and $Z$ is the diagonal in $Y$.
